# Dokka javadoc jar doesn't work with Intellij IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-dokka

I have following configuration in build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.dokka_version='0.9.15'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:$dokka_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka'

task dokkaJavadoc(type: org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaTask) {
    outputFormat = 'javadoc'
    outputDirectory = "$buildDir/dokkaJavadoc"
}

task packageJavadoc(type: Jar, dependsOn: 'dokkaJavadoc') {
    from "$buildDir/dokkaJavadoc"
    classifier = 'javadoc'
}

artifacts {
    archives packageJavadoc
}
```

This generates properly looking javadoc jar ("${moduleName}-javadoc.jar"). However when imported with Intellij Idea, while it is detected as javdoc jar, IDE support doesn't work. Is it format incompatibility with dokka-javadoc or gradle misconfiguration?